# How to gain admin privileges on D-Link router if my isp is not allowing me to do so?

Tags: router, administrator

I switched to new ISP yesterday, they gave me a D-Link router, can't use my old router. I want to change the wireless password, went to 192.168.1.1, I can login with the the username and password user user, but not as admin.

On the catalog it says that the default username and password are admin admin, tried that didn't work. Tried admin and no pass, tried many combinations, none worked.

I asked some other users and they said that the isp is blocking the users from logging in as admins, and blocking the reset button, and said that there's a hack where you do something like:

`cmd> telnet "router ip"` and do something like  `dumpcfg`

Could you please give a better explanation on how to gain admin privileges on your own router if your isp is not letting you do so by default?

For what it's worth, I live in [Lebanon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanon) and my ISP is [Ogero](http://www.ogero.gov.lb).

Comment: What model is the router?

Comment: @sgtbeano [DSL-2640U](http://www.dlink.ir/en/ADSLModem/WirelessADSLRouter/DSL_2640U)

Comment: Thanks, whilst I take a look - have you asked your ISP for admin access?

Comment: Try this - Username: admin & Password: password

Comment: @sgtbeano i'll try that tomorrow, today is a national holiday, but i don't think they will tell me how to do so, because others did ask them

Comment: @Rudolph tried that, didn't work, tried every combination that i can find on the web

Comment: @Fischer What OS are you using?  Are you happy with SSH?

Comment: Oh and who is your ISP?

Comment: @sgtbeano right now im on windows coz my linux isn't working but i'm a good linux user and i do know how to use SSH - you won't know who's my isp even if i tell you, i live in lebanon, a small country in the middle east

Comment: The reason I ask about SSH is that you could try flashing DD-WRT to your router, it appears to be supported -> http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dsl-2640u

Comment: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/router-pawning/ -- Scroll down to the bit about telnet, but there's a lot of information on that page.

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason you cannot purchase your own ADSL modem and change the MAC Address to match the modem you have.  From a technical perspective your ISP wouldn't be able to tel the difference.  I assume you are in some other country that isn't the US?

Comment: @sgtbeano i cracked the password, thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: @SamN password cracked

Comment: @Ramhound problem solved

Comment: @Rudolph thank you all guys for trying to help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to crack the password, I'll post the answer as a future reference to future users if you don't mind.

- Use Telnet (enable it if you're on windows) and connect your laptop to the router using a cable.
- Open a terminal or command prompt and type `telnet 192.168.1.1` or whatever your local IP is.
  my username and password are `user` and `user` they are usually the default username and password for non admin users.
- type `dumpcfg` and copy the output to a text file.
- the output is almost full of crap, so i'm not going to paste it, you're only interested, in two lines, the first is `sysUserName value=""` and the second is `sysPassword value=""` usually, it's `sysUserName value="admin"` and as for the password it's `sysPassword value="Base64EncodedString"`
- Go to a [Base64 decoder](http://www5.rptea.com/base64/), copy the encoded password string, and click `bas64 to normal string`. In my case, the encoded password was `<sysPassword value="bXkxMTAxMTM="/>` i decoded it, so my password was `my110113`.

I only tried that on D-Link router, I don't know about other routers, but as long as they use Base64, I see no reason why it shouldn't work, and it's not hacking, it's gaining administrative privileges on your own router.

Comment: So what was the password?  There is no security threat in sharing this information since we cannot actually connect to your router.

Comment: @Ramhound the encrypted password was `<sysPassword value="bXkxMTAxMTM="/>` i decrypted it, so my password was `my110113`

Comment: Interesting.  You might update your question and name who your ISP was.  I suspect many people might have the same password if they are in a similar position it might help them.

Comment: @Ramhound good point, done

Comment: @Fischer Quick FYI, it's generally a good practice on this site to mark the answer as "answered", even if you answered your own question (what a mouthful!)  There should be an outline of a check mark next to the answer that you posted. If you click that check mark, it'll turn green.

Comment: @MichaelH it says `you can accept your answer in 16 hours` so i'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, not an encryption.

Comment: This is terrible security.  Any user mode program would be able to open a connection to the telnet port, decode the password and gain admin access to the router.

Comment: @david25272 I guess you're right, what can i say? :)